# Salary Calculation in Excel

Tags: excel, function

So I have a problem that I'm dealing with for days now and I cant figure it out. I have this problem in excel, I am looking for assistance regarding a calculation. I want to be able to calculate a payment date schedule based on a set monthly payment date but to exclude exclude weekends and specific holiday dates e.g.
Here's My file I'm Working on:[[image: It didn't let me upload the excel file.]].

Here is some function that I already used : `=IF(TEXT(O2,"dddd")=$U$2,O2+2,IF(TEXT(O2,"dddd")=$U$3,O2+1,O2))`This works for only weekends, It doesn't work on holidays, I want it to work not only on weekends and on holidays too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out functions like networkdays.intl() ? What about making a list of holiday dates and checking with vlookup()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the WORKDAY() function together with the DATE() function.

B2 contains year - 2012
B3 contains payment day - 28
A5:A17 contain payment periods (month numbers) - 1..12
D6:D16 contain holidays

```
=WORKDAY(DATE($B$2,A6,$B$3-1),1,$D$6:$D$14)
```

Also see the linked image. (NB: My Excel version uses semi-colon ";" in stead of comma "," to separate arguments in functions.)

Best of luck!

Xharx

[Image of the Excel sheet solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4EkB.jpg)

Comment: Holiday Friday 28th of september 2021 -> payment date next Monday 1st of October. Seems to work as intended. Or do I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Example.]Here's How u Do it. First we have to have starting month from where were gonna start counting I made this formula which works great, `=WORKDAY(EDATE($B$15,COUNT($B$15:B17))-1,1,holiday1)`
were freezing the starting date and counting how many rows are we from the starting position , then were gonna minus 1 from it , and in days were gonna type 1, if there's holidays that I wanna exclude too I just can enter it and give it a name, (Some of u who doesn't understand this, its just saying that its referring to specified cells which we named holidays) and it works flawlessly.
B15 = starting month